# Creating a Python script to run an existing Python File

Tags: python, json, robotframework

I am trying to call  https://github.com/evidens/json2csv  script from my Robot Framework test.  I have seen examples creating new Python scripts and calling them in tests. I also installed the package, but I don't know how to create a Python script to execute this function passing the args from my Robot test. Any guidance please?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, and explain how the results you get are different than the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**example.robot file**

```
*** Settings ***

Library example.py

Documentation A test suite with a single test for valid login.

...

... This test has a workflow that is created using keywords in

    enter code here

... the imported resource file.

*** Variables ***

${Host} 0.0.0.0

${Port} 45141

*** Test Cases ***

example1

[Tags] example

[Documentation] Sample Test

smoke 4 1

example2

[Tags] example

[Documentation] Sample Test

smoke 3

example3

[Tags] example

[Documentation] Sample Test

smoke 6 1
```

**Example.py file**

'''

```
''if the test_no value is equal or greater than 4,

then the test is passed and if that condition fails, then

raise an exception to fail the test'''

def smoke(test_no,ser_flush=0):

if ser_flush=="1":

print("Serial flush")

else:

print("No serial Flush")

test_no=int(test_no)

try:

if test_no>=4:

print("Vailid number")

else:

raise ValueError('invalid')

except ValueError as e:

raise ValueError('invalid')
```

Now run in command line

```
python example.py example.robot
```

I guess this sample example would clear your doubts

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run that script specifically, or are you trying to convert JSON to CSV? It might be easier to work directly within your own Python script using the json and csv libraries, rather than an external library (ex: http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-json-to-csv-using-python/)

Edit: Perhaps you could also import the json2csv.py directly as a module? It's unclear to me exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to run that module from Robot framework test.

Comment: I have to a create a keyword to run this module, my trouble is creating the keyword itself.

Comment: I create a file 'test.py'  like this :                                                     ***************
import os
def JSONtoCSV(arg1,arg2):
     os.system("python json2csv.py arg1 arg2")

Comment: The solution I posted on  Apr 9th,  worked for me. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

**example.robot file**

*** Settings ***

Library example.py

Documentation A test suite with a single test for valid login.

...

... This test has a workflow that is created using keywords in

... the imported resource file.

*** Variables ***

${Host} 0.0.0.0

${Port} 45141

*** Test Cases ***

Test_1

[Tags] example

[Documentation] Sample Test

smoke 4 1

Test_2

[Tags] example

[Documentation] Sample Test

smoke 3

Test_3

[Tags] example

[Documentation] Sample Test

smoke 6 1

Answer (score 0):

Please refer RF documentation: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#keyword-names

Call Python Functions, within Robot Test Case